# What the meaning of "policy ACCEPT" and "policy DROP" in iptables?

Tags: security, iptables

When running `service iptables status` on 2 CentOS server,

- one server has `policy ACCEPT` in
  `Chain INPUT`, `Chain FORWARD`, and
  `Chain OUTPUT`
- another server has `policy DROP` in
  `Chain INPUT` and `Chain FORWARD`; while
  `policy ACCEPT` in `Chain OUTPUT`

What the meaning of `policy ACCEPT` and `policy DROP`?

...and how to change from `policy ACCEPT` to `policy DROP` and from `policy DROP` to `policy ACCEPT`?

Answer (score 48):

ACCEPT means that the default policy for that chain, if there are no matching rules, is to allow the traffic.

DROP does the opposite.

The following rule will change the policy for inbound traffic to DROP:

```
iptables --policy INPUT DROP
```

The manpage for iptables should be able to give you the rest of the info you would need to make other policy changes as necessary.

Comment: This may well not need saying but it is unwise to do the above on a server to which you are remotely logged in!

Comment: Right! Make yourself an exception for port 22 in the input chain first!

Comment: If i change input policy to accept, does it mean i have opened all ports or something, leaving my server exposed to random attacks? I am trying to fix input http connection issues(ssh works) and stumbled here while searching for why iptable says IINPUT policy is DROP

Answer (score 10):

The policy defines the target for packets that get to the end of the chain.